# Fixed Point Convergence. Finding the interval for which the iteration converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

I've solved the first part. I think I have something for the second part, but I'm unsure.

> A) You are given the fixed point problem $x=Ax^2$ where $A>0$ is a constant. Compute positive fixed point of the problem.

The fixed point is $1/A$, because  $1/A=A\, (1/A)^2$.

> B) For what values of $A>0$ will a fixed point iteration $p_n=A(p_{n-1})^2 $ converge to the positive fixed point?

I think this is from $0$ to $A=1/2$, $(0,1/2)$ but am unsure.
This is because the convergence theorem.
If we set $g(x)=Ax^2$ and compute derivative $2Ax$, then $2Ax\leq K<1$ according to the convergence theorem, the derivative has to be less than some constant $K$ which is less than $1$ on the interval of convergence. Therefore 
$Ax<1/2$ $\implies$ $A<1/2$ for the sequence to converge.

Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of $A\,x^2$ evaluated at $x=1/A$ is $2$ for all $A$. The fixed point iteration will never converge to $1/A$ except if $x_0=1/A$. If $0\le x_0<1/A$ it will converge to the aerator $0$. If $x>1/A$ it will converge to $\infty$.